# For & Do While loop returns unexpected counting result

Tags: excel, vba

In the below code, the value of `Counter` is not as expected.

```
Counter = 0
Srate = 0.55
Prate = 0.03

For i = 0 To 99
    Do While Srate <= Rnd()
        Counter = Counter + 1
        Srate = Srate + Prate
    Loop

    Counter = Counter + 1
    i = i + 1
Next

'result
MsgBox(i) = 100
MsgBox (Counter) < 100
```

I was expecting `Counter > 100` because counter is getting incremented by `1` but I am getting the value of `Counter < 100`.

Comment: Never mess with the counter variable `i = i + 1` inside a `For` loop. `Next` automatically increases `i` by `1` while in `Do` loops you need to increase manually. Remove `i = i + 1`.

Comment: oh my teacher : D
got the answer, question solved, happy
i am expressing my gratitude !

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: That is a valid answer. You may want to put it as one?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Well, posted it as an answer.

Comment: @ANOMEL: Please do not put solved in the question title. You may want to see [Is it OK to add Solved to the title of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question)

Comment: Also if you really want to mark the question as "Solved" then you may want to see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout
i understood it's not good. Sorry i appologize. 
i thought, Solved Text will make time saving.
and asking for my being lousy at english.

Comment: No need to apologize. It happens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mess with the counter variable `i` in a `For i = … To …` loop.

The `Next` automatically increases `i` by `1` in `For` loops, while in `Do` loops you need to increase manually.

The solution her is to remove `i = i + 1`:

```
For i = 0 To 99
    Do While Srate <= Rnd()
        Counter = Counter + 1
        Srate = Srate + Prate
    Loop

    Counter = Counter + 1
Next i 'increases i by 1 automatically
```

Comment: And for those who do want to mess with the `For` loop, using `For  = 0 to 99 step x` and put what you want the new increment. Or `For  = 99 to 0 step -x` for a decrement